# VBA Explanation of Code

Tags: vba

Consider the following code:

```
Sub Sequence()
'
' Sequence Macro
'

'
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9"), Type:= _
    xlFillDefault
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9").Select
End Sub
```

What does R1C1 represent? It seems to be a position. Also how does the offset function work? Does the ActiveCell.Offset(1,0) indicate that we move down one row?

Answer (score 0):

R1C1 is the name of one of the many ways of referencing a cell in Excel. R stands for 'row' and C stands for 'column'. You should be able to get information on the methods by selecting them in the VB editor and hitting F1